# github copilot does not suggest anything anymore after i fiddled around with vscodes settings for auto suggestions / completes

Tags: autocomplete, autosuggest

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

those are the things i tested around disabling/enabling. there might be more options i changed but I cant remember which ones.
anyway all of a sudden copilot does not suggest anything anymore. those 3 options above are all set to true and the copilot icon in the bottom right of vscode tells me that it's running.

what could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

I was playing with those settings too and found Copilot not working all of a sudden.

Inspect your settings via the JSON file and see if you see any other option you don't know about and play with that.

In my case, `"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false` was the problem. Set it to `true` and Copilot should be back up again.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this question while I was searching for a solution regarding the same problem but for JetBrains WebStorm IDE.
Writing it here in case someone else has the same need: for me, it was enough to just go over the Github Copilot settings among the Webstorm preferences and enable the checkbox in the screenshot, that has been disabled in an unclear way (since I didn't disable it on my own).

[image: Webstorm Github Copilot settings]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I somehow had `"github.copilot.inlineSuggest.enable": false` in my configuration, commenting it resolved it.